# How to change Magento timezone?

Tags: magento-1.9, timezone

I have used **`Magento 1.9`** initially timezone was **`America/Los_Angeles`** in **`app/etc/config.xml`** file and set **India/Calcutta timezone** in

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options ->Timezone

at that time Magento function `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` return correct date.
But order placed time was **-5:30 to real time.**

For set **Asia/Calcutta timezone,** I have changed **`app/etc/config.xml`** **`general->locale->timezone`** to **`Asia/Calcutta`** and in **`app/Mage.php`** I have changed **`UTC`** to **`Asia/Calcutta`**,

And it has changed the timezone in the backend, it means order placed time is correct as real-time but the function `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` return me **+5:30 time to real time.**

Is there any place where I missed to change?

Or Is there another method to change the timezone of the Magento store?

Answer (score 9):

You can set timezone from Admin panel ,

Go to :

> System => Configuration => General => Locale Options =>Timezone

[image]

**AND**

Change the default timezon in file **app/Mage.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Replace above line with following

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

**AND**

Copy file **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php** then find line 38

```
const DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = 'UTC';
```

Replace above line with following

```
const DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';
```

**Note**: If still it will not work. Dig in to following function in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php`.

```
public function storeDate($store=null, $date=null, $includeTime=false, $format = null)
    {
        $timezone = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
        $date = new Zend_Date($date, $format, $this->getLocale());
        $date->setTimezone($timezone);
        if (!$includeTime) {
            $date->setHour(0)
                ->setMinute(0)
                ->setSecond(0);
        }
        return $date;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have already set `India Standard time (Asia/Calcutta)` in Timezone.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari Check updated answer

Comment: Hello @Rohit, this is not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

you have to set your timezone manually

first go to

`app/etc/config.xml`  add your time zone here

```
<general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
```

second go to `app/Mage.php`

on line `768`

change this line too

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

to your `timezone`

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

Comment: Hello @Qaisar Satti, please read my question, both changes I have already made but the problem is  `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` function return me incorrect time +5:30 to real time. Is there any place where I missed to change?

Comment: did you check with new order time is correct?

Comment: Yes I have said in my question that order place time is correct.

Comment: did you refresh the cache? delete `var/cache` folder because for after these it good to go

Comment: Yes I refresh cache from backend and also remove from var/cache folder.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, Thank you. it's worked for me. I have just tried.

Comment: You shouldn't change Magento core files.

Comment: @RicardoMartins keep up the good work.

Comment: In my case, the order created time is correct, just EDT. Btw, after Mar 11,2018, the order confirmation email's content shows me the "EDT + 5" ( same with UTC+1). Even though when i changed the Mage.php, locale.php and config.xml, the order confirmation email showed me the EDT+1 date. It's very wired. Is there any solution? I already matched with server time, web server time and store timezone. - Server time - EDT. - Web server time: America/New_York, - magento time: America/New_York. Hope good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your locale settings are defined in the configuration under System => Configuration => General => Locale Options =>Timezone, and can be set per website scope.

You can quickly get/change in your `core_config_data` table (`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'general/locale/timezone';`).

**You might use `Mage::getModel('core/date')` for getting current time and date.**

---

Getting formatted date based on locale settings:

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
# return 22/10/2017 23:30:21

echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp();
# return current timestamp

echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtTimestamp());
# returo current date in GMT timezone, doesn't matter your locale settings
```

[image]
See `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Date.php` for a complete list of methods available.

My suggestion is: try to convert everything to GMT using this model's GMT methods, and stop worrying about php.ini, magento XML, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you have to use Asia/Kolkata instead of Asia/Calcutta