# Order time stamp off by 6 hours in the order Confirmation Email. It is CORRECT on the order itself in the Admin panel

Tags: timezone

The orders have correct date/time stamps in the Admin Panel (Sales - Orders - click an order open - under Order Date --) Apr 9, 2016 **3:07:57 AM**) but the time is off by exactly 6 hours in the Customer Confirmation Email --)

> Your order #100006833 Placed on April 9, 2016 **9:07:57 AM MDT**

We are in Colorado (MST) and I have the following setup in Admin Panel => System => Configuration => General => Locale Options => Timezone => Mountain Standard Time (America/Denver)

When I asked the hosting company what the server time was - they said Central Time Zone (the server is in Chicago).

We use a third party to send out the Confirmation Emails if that makes a difference? **SendGrid** setup in the Admin panel via a ASCHRODER EXTENSION.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to you - in our case the timestamps were exactly 4 hours off in our e-mail log. Although the timezone was set to our local time (Australia/Melbourne), it turns out our server was in the Detroit time zone, but Magento *thought* it was in UTC... so it missed the additional 4 hour difference between those two zones when calculating it.

Thanks to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105549/5073), I was able to fix the problem by changing the timezone in `app/Mage.php` (line 768 on my copy) from `UTC` to `America/Detroit`. In your case I'm guessing setting this to `America/Chicago` might solve your problem.

(You can also confirm what timezone your server is in by creating a blank PHP file, putting `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and running it, and looking for a listing under `date.timezone`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Magento 2.4. I resolved this issue by setting the server time as UTC through WHM or PHP.INI. Change the timezone to your local timezone in Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale options.

FYI, Magento by default saves all dates as UTC, it will display the correct time based on the timezone you set up in the admin.