# Cronjob trouble after changing timezone

Tags: cron, time

After made that: [How to change Magento timezone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105546/how-to-change-magento-timezone)

My magento regional time was Europe/Paris but I tried to change to Europe/Budapest (both are the same..)

AOE Scheduler says

> Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and
>   your configuration!

What I have made:

Mage.php (before)

```
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Mage.php (after)

```
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Budapest');
```

config.xml (before)

```
        <locale>
            <code>en_US</code>
            <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
        </locale>
```

config.xml (after)

```
        <locale>
            <code>en_US</code>
            <timezone>Europe/Budapest</timezone>
        </locale>
```

I tried to

1. Disable all schedules and remove programmed
2. Disable cron job system
3. Enable cron job system again
4. Enable all schedules and re build programs.

But the problem keeps :/

Is like the cron job hour is advanced (real hour 11:36 in Spain):
[image: Cronjob time bad]

Sugestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Do NOT change **Mage.php** file, only **config.xml** and cron jobs will work fine at time.

Disable all jobs and remove scheduled taks, enable again and all wil be synced.