# Is it OK to modify app/Mage.php to edit the date_default_timezone_set value in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, timezone

Is it OK to modify `app/Mage.php` to edit the `date_default_timezone_set` value?

I've modified my timezone in magento at `System => General => Locale Options => Timezone`, and set it to `America/New_York`, but it's still showing UTC time and every time based function is keying off of UTC time.

When I look at `app/Mage.php` it shows:

```
if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
    $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
        self::$_isInstalled = true;
    }
}
```

Thus, I assume I have to modify `date_local_timezone_set` from UTC to `America/New_York`? But is it OK to modify the `app/Mage.php` in this manner?

Thank you.

Comment: modifying mage is not at all reccommended.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar Ok. So how do I get this to change? My server time is Pacific Time (PST), my local time is Eastern Time (EST), and Magento's time is apparently UTC.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended, but unfortunately it is required if you want to effectively synchronize Magento & your local timezone... as this had been a (really annoying) bug since day 1 & never fixed

More details here

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105547/3566